# Compactness under different metric?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness, solution-verification

Consider the metric $\rho(x,y)=\frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|}$ on $\mathbb{R}$. Is $(\mathbb{R},\rho)$ compact?

In order to show that is not, I wanted to find a sequence such  that any subsequence is non-convergent and I considered $x_n=n$. Does this work or I missed something?

Comment: Well, you still need to prove that there is no subsequence that converges.

Comment: It seems that $\rho(n, 0) \to 1$ so $x_n \to 1$

Comment: @Hayden For that I only need to show that $x_n\xrightarrow{\rho} \infty$ right?

Comment: Yes, you could show that every subsequence is unbounded, but Mathmo123 shows that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{\rho(n,0)}$ is finite, so it may not be that straight-forward

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative approach to your problem:

First, show that the function $f:(\Bbb R,\rho) \to (\Bbb R, |\cdot|)$ taking $x \mapsto x$ is continuous.  Now, the continuous image of a compact set is compact.

So, suppose that $\Bbb R$ were compact under $\rho$.  Then since $f$ is continuous, $f(\Bbb R) = \Bbb R$ would be compact under $|\cdot|$.  Since this is not true, we have derived a contradiction.

Comment: You did not write what is $f$. I guess you mean the function $f(x)=x$.

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Every metric space $(M,d)$ determines the associated topological space $(M,\mathcal{O})$ whose open sets $U\in\mathcal{O}$ are the unions of open balls of the metric space. Compactness of a metric space is a *topological* property, meaning that the metric space is compact iff the associated topological space is compact. Two homeomorphic topological spaces have the same topological properties; in particular, they are either both compact or neither is compact.

In your case let $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ be the usual metric on $\mathbb{R}$. Then the identity function  $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R} : x\mapsto x$ is a uniformly continuous mapping from the metric space $(\mathbb{R},d)$ to the metric space $(\mathbb{R},\rho)$, while its inverse, which is also the identity function, is a uniformly continuous mapping from the metric space $(\mathbb{R},\rho)$ to the metric space $(\mathbb{R},d)$.  It follows that the topological spaces associated with the two metrics on $\mathbb{R}$ are homeomorphic,
and since this particular homeomorphism is the identity on $\mathbb{R}$, the two topological spaces are in fact identical.  In short, the metric $\rho$ determines the same topology on $\mathbb{R}$ as the metric $d$, which is the topology of the real line. Now the answer to your question is obvious, is it not?

By the way, instead of the metric $\varrho$ you can choose the metric $\alpha(x,y)=\min(|x-y|,a)$, where $a$ is a (fixed) strictly positive real number, say $a=10^{-1000}$.
As above, the identity mapping is uniformly continuous from the metric space $(\mathbb{R},d)$ to the metric space $(\mathbb{R},\alpha)$, and the same is true in the opposite direction, so the topology determined by the metric $\alpha$ is the usual topology of the real line.

Comment: Two topological spaces associated with two metrics as in this case can be homeomorphic but the two metrics may not be equivalent right? By equivalent I mean to exist, $c,C$ such that $cd(x,y)\leq\rho(x,y)\leq Cd(x,y)$.

Comment: You are right. Of course, if two metrics (on the same set) *are* equivalent, the topological spaces associated with them coincide. The converse is not true: the metric $\rho$ in the question, as well as the metric $\alpha$ in my answer, demonstrate this.

Comment: Nice answer, but with one caveat. *Uniform* continuity is not relevant. It is enough that the identity be continuous from topology #1 to topology #2 and from topology #2 to topology #1.

Comment: @Lee Mosher: you are right. But, since the identity mapping is uniformly continuous in both directions, I said so. Here's an example of two metrics $\beta$ and $\gamma$ on $\mathbb{R}$ such that the identity mapping is continuous in both directions but uniformly continuous in neither: $\beta(x,y) := |e^x-e^y|$, $\gamma(x,y) := |e^{-x}-e^{-y}|$.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that 'truncating' the distance function $d(x,y)$ to $\alpha(x,y):=\min(d(x,y),a)$, for a fixed $a>0$ (which can be arbitrarily small), works in any metric space $(M,d)$. Imagine $M$ inhabited by uniformly myopic point-creatures that clearly see only those other point-creatures, and distances to them, that are no farther away than $a$ -- everything beyond this visibility horizon they declare to be at the distance $a$ from them. This myopic metric is uniformly isomorphic to the original metric. What this means is that the notion of a metric space is 'uniformly local'

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, the sequence defined by $x_n = n$ works.
To see this, let $y_n = x_{\phi(n)}$ be a subsequence.
Let $y\in\mathbb R$. We have
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{|y_n-y|}{1+|y_n-y|} &= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{|\phi(n)-y|}{1+|\phi(n)-y|}\\
&= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{|\phi(n)-y|}{1+|\phi(n)-y|}\times\frac{1+\phi(n)}{1+\phi(n)}\times\frac{\phi(n)}{\phi(n)}\\
&= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{|\phi(n)-y|}{\phi(n)}\times\frac{1+\phi(n)}{1+|\phi(n)-y|}\times\frac{\phi(n)}{1+\phi(n)} \\
&= \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{\phi(n)}{1+\phi(n)}=1
\end{align}$$ so that $(y_n)$ doesn't converge to $y$.

Comment: I didn't understand the notation on the last part of your answer.

Comment: When $n$ tends to $+\infty$, we have that $|\phi(n)-y|$ is close $\phi(n)$. More rigorously, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{|\phi(n)-y|}{\phi(n)} = 1$. Similarly, we have $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1+|\phi(n)-y|}{1+\phi(n)} = 1$. I edit my answer.